# style.transform in angular2 not adding style attribute to element

Tags: angular

In Angular2, I can't seem to set the transform style via this syntax:

```
[style.transform]="'translate(100px,0px)'
```

By comparison, this does work on the same element:

```
[style.backgroundColor]="'red'"
```

Comment: i think you have to put browser prefix

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate. If not, add a comment to get it reopened.